# Automagically including a join when needed in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I'm building a class about a set of tables. One of those dables, TableDates, includes a field TableDates.date which I use to filter for periods. That's easy. Assuming query already have the needed select construct:

```
query = query.filter(TableDates.date < date)
```

And it works when query already included a proper join with TableDates.

But in some cases, y have a query that does not include a proper join with it. In those cases, I should use:

```
query = query.join(TableDates).filter(TableDates.date < date)
```

And here is the problem. I would like to include this filter code in an object method that would work both with queries that already joined TableDates, or not. Of course, I can track in my own methods when I join with TableDates, to decide if I have to include join(TableDates) in the query or not. But my question is: Is there a way of letting SQLAlchemy do the job? I've browsing the documentation, and I didn't find a clue, but maybe I missed it.

More in particular, I was thinking of either:

- Having a way of checking a query to know if TableDates is already joined in it.
- Having a way of writting the join(TableDates) in a way that if it is already joined in query, it does nothing (of course, if I just try to add that join when TableDates is already joined, I get an exception stating that I cannot joint it with itself).

Comment: If there's a relationship to TableDates, you can use any() instead.  The query is not as efficient but no JOIN or change to the query's overall structure is needed.   otherwise, digging into the query structure is a more elaborate and error prone endeavor (you'd have to poke into query._from_obj, not always a simple task).

Comment: the fact that it's very difficult to predict how this JOIN would be made is exactly why SQLA doesn't try to make a guess like that for you.   my suggestion overall would be to reorganize the code so that it doesn't have this issue.

Comment: OK, thanks. If there is no other feedback, probably the best thing is to try to rearchitect the code.